# Борьба с GC, из-за которого другие потоки блокируются

Tags: c#, .net, оптимизация, производительность, сборщик-мусора

Сделал дамп памяти своего сетевого асинхронного приложения и прошелся по нему такой замечательной утилитой, как `DebugDiag 2 Analysis` от `Microsoft`. Она выдала ошибку и предупреждение, вот их содержание:

---

**Error:**

> In NetworkApplication.DMP GC is running in this process. The Thread
>   that triggered the GC is 330.

**Warning:**

> This thread is waiting for .net garbage collection to finish.  Thread
>   330 triggered the garbage collection. The gargage collector thread
>   wont start doing its work till the time the threads which have
>   pre-emptive GC disabled have finished executing.  The following
>   threads have pre-emptive GC disabled 330.
>
> 89,45% of threads blocked (534 threads).

---

Рекомендации по исправлению, которые дала тулза:

**Error:**

> When a GC is running the .NET objects are not in a valid state and the
>   reported analysis may be inaccurate. Also, the thread that triggered
>   the Garbage collection may or may not be a problematic thread. Too
>   many garbage collections in a process are bad for the performance of
>   the application. Too many GC's in a process may indicate a memory
>   pressure or symptoms of fragmenation. Review the blog [ASP.NET Case
>   Study: High CPU in GC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2006/06/22/asp-net-case-study-high-cpu-in-gc-large-objects-and-high-allocation-rates/) - Large objects and high allocation rates
>   for more details.

**Warning:**

> Review the callstacks for the threads that have preemptive GC Disabled
>   to see what they are doing which is preventing the GC to run.  Review
>   the blog [.NET Hang Case Study: The GC-Loader Lock Deadlock](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2007/03/12/net-hang-case-study-the-gc-loader-lock-deadlock-a-story-of-mixed-mode-dlls/) (a
>   story of mixed mode dlls) that gives some information on how to debug
>   these issue more.

---

Соответственно приложение асинхронное и работает на потоках `ThreadPool` с дефолтными настройками. Версия `.NET: 4.6.2 x64`, перевел для более оптимальной работы `RyuJIT`, который в первых версиях работал не очень хорошо. Может быть это даже и плюс, потому что в этой версии фреймворка доступны новые методы управления сборщиком мусора. ОC: `Windows Server 2012 r2 x64`.

**Вопрос:** Вообще с `GC` возможно как то бороться в данном случае (когда он начинает `"втыкать"` не по детски)? Что нужно оптимизировать? Какие советы можете дать или как лично боролись с подобными проблемами (тоже интересно почерпнуть чужой опыт).

*p.s. приводить какой либо пример кода нерационально, приложение большое, много кода.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ИМХО, бороться с GC не надо. Надо стараться избегать лишнего, неоправданного memory traffic'а. Тема нетривиальная, но можно выделить два основных совета:

1. Избегать ненужного "старения" объектов (переходов из Gen0 -> Gen1 ->
   Gen2);
2. Избегать частого создания/пересоздания объектов, попадающих в LOH (Large object heap, туда попадают объекты размером более 85000
   байт).

P.S.: Попробуйте проанализировать дамп вашего процесса при помощи утилиты **WinDBG** при помощи команды `!DumpHeap -stat` (подробнее можно почитать на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx)). Посмотрите объектов какого типа подозрительно много, проанализируйте историю создания этих объектов (команда `GCRoot`).

Comment: +1. Профилировать, смотреть и чинить. Также можно посмотреть [доклад](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cg5Vc8LNs6g) джетбрейнсовцев, которые активно борются с мемори траффиком в Решарпере.

Comment: @andreycha, после изучения проблемы хотел бы еще добавить что здорово помогает сжатие LOH (доступно с .NET 4.5.1), и дабы не пинали мою архитектуру скажу что много LOH объектов генерируется самим фреймворком в том же SslStream.

Comment: @Alexis ммм, сжатие же позволит уменьшить memory footprint, но при этом время на GC увеличится. А у вас, я так понял, проблема как раз в частых и долгих сборках?

Comment: @andreycha, Вы правы, но на самом деле проблемы две. Первая - при длительной работе из-за несжатого LOH софт постепенно понемногу снижает производительность, поэтому теперь в цикле после нескольких тысяч итерация сжимаю LOH. Вторая проблема - да, в очень частых сборках, убрал весь Linq, сделал всевозможные отпимизации (посмотрел кучу видеоматериалов джетбрейнсовцев) - стало полегче. Но всеравно сильно втыкает. Я думаю это уже особенность .NET. Можете дать совет если сталкивались с подобным - стоит ли заморачиваться дальше, оптимизировать или же по времени проще переписать на тот же C++?

Comment: @Alexis в качестве дополнительного инструмента анализа могу посоветовать [Heap Allocations Viewer](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/06/06/heap-allocations-viewer-plugin/), если используете Решарпер, или [аналог на Roslyn](https://github.com/Microsoft/RoslynClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer), если не используете. Иногда помогает найти "продолб", как выражаются в ДжетБрейнс :). Вообще все проблемы с GC и памятью, с которым я сталкивался, решались при помощи профайлеров и небольших переделок. Я не знаю, как далеко вы уже зашли в расследовании, поэтому давать советы о переписывании не могу.

Comment: @Alexis что вам профайлер говорит? У вас генерится много gen0 траффика или наоборот, много объектов сидит в gen2? Сколько вы вообще времени в GC проводите? И опять же вопрос: все это разбирательство только из-за того, что вам тула что-то показала, или вы *на самом деле* выезжаете за пределы по производительности/потреблению памяти?

Comment: @Alexis кстати, было бы интересно почитать, если бы вы написали статейку на тот же Хабр (или в блог, если ведете) о проведенной работе :). Все-таки формат SO не всегда позволяет в полной мере рассказать о проблеме.